# Finding the first number of a .txt file - Java

Tags: java, text, bufferedreader, filereader

I have different `.txt` files, which should be read by Java. Then java should give me the first number of first line or if I say differently, the first number of 4th word.

For instance:

`"AAAAAA B Version 5.0.1"`  or `"AAAAAA B Version  6.0.2"`

5 or 6 should be the resulting number.

I've tried some methods such as bufferedReader with line.charAt but I don't know how I can make it work for my problem. What would you guys suggest ?

```
BufferedReader br = null;
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\new2.txt")));
String line = null;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] parts = line.startsWith(...?.); 
    System.out.println("");
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for regular expressions

Comment: @TimB yeah I've tried that with patterns and matches as well. Maybe since I am now that experienced in java, I couldn't make it work.

Comment: @tolgazinho Show us the expression (edit it into your post).  We can help you fix it.

Comment: ::sigh:: `line.split("\\s")[3].split("\\.")[0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all just read First line of the file.

```
File f=new File("your_file.txt");
FileReader fr=new FileReader(f);
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
String firstLine=br.readLine();
```

Then split the line by spaces to get String array of words

```
String[] words=firstLine.split("\\s+");
```

Split the fourth word using " . "

```
String[] nos=words[3].split("\\.");
    System.out.println(nos[0]);//Expected output, First number of fourth 
//word in first line of given file
```

Comment: this one works very well but the problem is String[] words=firstLine.split(" "); because i dont have same number of spaces between the words. Sometimes 4 spaces can be found between them. could it be without space?

Comment: Now you can get it! i have changed in answer

Comment: Yes, it works very fine. Thanks a lot for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(Your string here);

if(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

It tries to find a negative or positive integer and prints it if it can find any.

Comment: tries to find a negative or positive integer and prints it if it can find any

Comment: @newbieee Edit your post to explain, explanations in comments are not very visible ;-)

Comment: @newbieee Sorry, i dont understand it clearly. How can I input my text file here?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the fourth word in each line is supposed to be the version number just grab that word and get the first character. If its not necessarily the fourth word try using indexOf() on the line and then get the character before that, that is if you know for sure each line is set up this way.

I meant to say if each line is known to have the format you showed above you should be able to use IndexOf() on the decimal.

> AAAAAA B Version 5(.)0.1

Or use split() to split white space and get each word

```
parts = line.split(" ");
```

Comment: yes, it's always 4th word. This is important because, it effects some settings in program if the version is not the chosenone.

Comment: Try using the split then to save each word to your words array then go through the fourth word. It will be the first character.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, make sure that you post your full code. It's much easier to diagnose the problem when you actually have the information along-side it.
Secondly, what you're going to want is a scanner that's declared to read this .txt file.

A regular scanner is delcared like this:

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

This will read the system imput for your own file. however, you could change system.in to your file if you declare the file as a variable.

Comment: Why would you read `System.in` instead of an input stream reading the file?